# AWS CodeDeploy Agent pointed to wrong endpoint

Tags: aws-code-deploy

Installed the CodeDeploy Agent using the following:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y ruby wget
wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-west-2.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/latest/install
chmod +x ./install
```

However, the logs indicate it is pointed to the wrong region:

```
 [codedeploy-agent(9911)]: CodeDeploy endpoint: https://codedeploy-commands.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

I attempted to change the configuration:

```
---
:log_aws_wire: false
:log_dir: '/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/'
:pid_dir: '/opt/codedeploy-agent/state/.pid/'
:program_name: codedeploy-agent
:root_dir: '/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root'
:verbose: false
:wait_between_runs: 1
:proxy_uri:
:max_revisions: 5
:endpoint: https://codedeploy-commands.us-west-2.amazon.com
/etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml (END)
```

Restarted the service but still pointed to the wrong region?